# Is it possible to use format strings to align NSStrings like numbers can be?

Tags: objective-c, format-string

I'm using **NSLog()** to print some tabular data consisting of an **NSString** and an associated **integer**.

Assume I know the length of the longest word.

Is there a way using **format strings** to get this kind of column alignment:

> ```
> word:tree        rank:5  
> word:frog        rank:3  
> word:house       rank:2  
> word:peppercorn  rank:2  
> word:sword       rank:2  
> word:antlion     rank:1
> ```

The reason I'm asking about formatting strings is I'm hoping for a lightweight way to format my ghetto debugging output.

**Here is what I tried:**

```
NSString *word = @"tree";
NSUInteger rank = 4;
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"word:%-20@ rank:%u", word, rank];
NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

**Result:**

*word:tree rank:4*

No effect at all.

Comment: hahaha +1 for ghetto-debugging tag

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following seems to work, but requires conversion from your NSString's to C-strings.

```
NSString *word = @"tree";
NSUInteger rank = 4;
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"word:%-20s rank:%u", [word UTF8String], rank];
NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

Don't know why the field width is being ignored when trying to use an NSString.

Comment: what is you have a complete string (e.g 1 Item1 6 0% 6 ) how would that be?

Comment: @Anthony Cramp : it won't work if string length is more....What if want to trim string if string length is more than column length...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just like `printf`.

According to [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265), `stringWithFormat:` obeys the IEEE `printf` specification, which allows all kinds of modifications on the individual arguments.  The documentation has a restricted subset of that information, but they link to the [OpenGroup `printf` specification for Unix](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html) to give the full information (worth a read, you can accomplish a lot of tricks with format specifiers).

Try this, to get exactly what you've pasted above:

```
NSString *word = @"butterfly";
NSUInteger rank = 4;
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"word:%-11s rank:%u", [word UTF8String], rank];
```

Here's an example of how I format my debugging output (I don't use `NSLog`, I wrap printing to standard error to get file and line, too):

```
fprintf(stderr, "%s | %30s:%-5d | %s", [[[NSDate date] description] UTF8String],
    [fileName UTF8String], line, [body UTF8String]);
```

Comment: What do you get if the word is "tree". I get "word:tree rank:4" which doesn't seem to react to the column specifier.

Comment: @willc2: I've edited my answer with Anthony's information, give that a try.

Comment: @JedSmith, may I know how to do it in Swift? TYIA

Answer (score 0):

If you do something like the earlier answer:

```
NSString *word = @"tree";
NSUInteger rank = 4;
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"word:%-20s rank:%u", [word UTF8String], rank];
NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

... you can get encoding-conversion problems for non-ASCII characters... stringWithFormat seems to assume the system default encoding, which is still MacRoman for some crazy reason. You can drop down to the stdlib level -- do all your formatting with `sprintf` into your own buffer, and then you can control the encoding when creating an NSString from that -- but that's cumbersome. If anyone knows a convenient workaround, I'm all ears.