# Format strings objective c

Tags: objective-c, format-string

i found this
[Is it possible to use format strings to align NSStrings like numbers can be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671531/is-it-possible-to-use-format-strings-to-align-nsstrings-like-numbers-can-be)

I have a similar task but the opposite format.

```
   TOTAL:      2
SUBTOTAL:   6.00
     TAX:     0%
    CASH:  12.00
```

my code is this

```
NSString* item [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%-10s %@", @"TOTAL",@"2"];
```

Yet outcome is this

```
TOTAL:   2
SUBTOTAL:  6.00
```

**UPDATE**

I got it to work with this code.

```
NSString* item [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%12s %7s", [total UTF8String],[amount UTF8String]];
```

**UPDATE QUESTION**

What if the text is too long?

```
THIS TEXT IS TOO LONG
```

I want it to be

```
THIS TEXT
IS TOO LONG
```

Comment: The answer in the link states that you need to convert your NSString's to C-Strings using `UTF8String`.

Comment: yes. i did. but what i want is the opposite format stated on the link.

Comment: Try put an empty string in front, something like `@"%-10s%@ %@", @"", @"TOTAL", @"2"`

Comment: unfortunately, the `NSString` does not support the sign `-` (minus) for the strings. there is no warning or error when you try to use, it is just simply not working.

Comment: There is no way to break a long string using format specifiers.

Comment: But would it be possible if i won't use format specifiers? even though format specifiers is not on my mind when thinking for a solution.